# How to Reset/Cycle Power to a PCIe Device?

Tags: devices, power-management, pci

I have a PCIe device that only works correctly when the computer is fully powered off then on again. Issuing a simple `reboot` or `reboot -p` command does not appear to cycle the power to the PCIe card, which causes it not to work after the reboot.

Is there a way to, from the OS, cycle power to a device in a PCIe slot? I can find it in `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000*/`, but I can't figure out how to properly reset the board. Toggling power seems to be the only way.

Barring that, can I change a setting somewhere that will cause a full power cycle on a `reboot` command?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 by the way.

Comment: Did you try `reboot -f`? This is similar to pressing the power button of the CPU.

Comment: Two years ago the OP pointed out that a soft `reboot` didn't work. Your `reboot -f` is still a soft reboot.

Answer (score 38):

##### Remove the device and rescan the PCIe bus

Removing the PCIe device via the `remove` function in its directory and reloading it via the PCIe bus' `rescan` function causes the kernel to power-cycle the PCIe device without rebooting your computer.

```bash
echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/DDDD\:BB\:DD.F/remove
sleep 1
echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

In the above code, `DDDD:BB:DD.F` is the device slot format [Domain:Bus:Device.Function](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci).

Comment: echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/rescan is worked for me in lenovo g560 mini pci slot. I plugged in USB 3.0 minipci card. System is Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Comment: It doesn't work for all devices. I've got a Cavium network adapter that isn't power-off by that method as I can still access its u-boot when using a serial line.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I might suggest adding that you can use `lspci` to look for the Domain:Bus:Device:Function; I found mine listed as "Network controller" with a value of `00:14.3`.

Comment: Worked on Xilinx ZCU106 with dual Samsung SSDs connected via the HPC0 port.

Comment: This sequence helped me to reset, in initramfs, a PCI NVMe SSD which was unable to enumerate because of the error "frozen state error detected, reset controller".

Answer (score 23):

Resets in PCI express are a bit complex.  There are two main types of resets - conventional reset, and function-level reset.  There are also two types of conventional resets, fundamental resets and non-fundamental resets.  See the PCI express specification for all of the details.

A 'cold reset' is a fundamental reset that takes place after power is applied to a PCIe device.  There appears to be no standard way of triggering a cold reset, save for turning the system off and back on again.  On my machines, the `/sys/bus/pci/slots` directory is empty.

A 'warm reset' is a fundamental reset that is triggered without disconnecting power from the device.  There appears to be no standard way of triggering a warm reset.

A 'hot reset' is a conventional reset that is triggered across a PCI express link.  A hot reset is triggered either when a link is forced into electrical idle or by sending TS1 and TS2 ordered sets with the hot reset bit set.  Software can initiate a hot reset by setting and then clearing the secondary bus reset bit in the bridge control register in the PCI configuration space of the bridge port upstream of the device.

A 'function-level reset' (FLR) is a reset that affects only a single function of a PCI express device.  It must not reset the entire PCIe device.  Implementing function-level resets is not required by the PCIe specification.  A function-level reset is initiated by setting the initiate function-level reset bit in the function's device control register in the PCI express capability structure in the PCI configuration space.

Linux exposes the function-level reset functionality in the form of `/sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/reset`.  Writing a 1 to this file will initiate a function-level reset on the corresponding function.  Note that this only affects that specific function of the device, not the whole device, and devices are not required to implement function-level resets as per the PCIe specification.

I am not aware of any 'nice' method for triggering a hot reset (there is no sysfs entry for that).  However, it is possible to use setpci to do so:

```
#!/bin/bash

dev=$1

if [ -z "$dev" ]; then
    echo "Error: no device specified"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -e "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev" ]; then
    dev="0000:$dev"
fi

if [ ! -e "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev" ]; then
    echo "Error: device $dev not found"
    exit 1
fi

port=$(basename $(dirname $(readlink "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev")))

if [ ! -e "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$port" ]; then
    echo "Error: device $port not found"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Removing $dev..."

echo 1 > "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/remove"

echo "Performing hot reset of port $port..."

bc=$(setpci -s $port BRIDGE_CONTROL)

echo "Bridge control:" $bc

setpci -s $port BRIDGE_CONTROL=$(printf "%04x" $(("0x$bc" | 0x40)))
sleep 0.01
setpci -s $port BRIDGE_CONTROL=$bc
sleep 0.5

echo "Rescanning bus..."

echo 1 > "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$port/rescan"
```

Ensure that all attached drivers are unloaded before running this script.  This script will attempt to remove the PCIe device, then command the upstream switch port to issue a hot reset, then attempt to rescan the PCIe bus.  This script has also only been tested on devices with a single function, so it may need some reworking for devices with multiple functions.

Comment: This script worked for my AMD RX480. Context: PCI passthrough to a Win10 guest, then shutting down or rebooting the guest. Starting the guest again (without using this script) would hang if the GPU was still attached. Running this script in between fixed the issue

Comment: Is there any way to cut power to the PCIe device using this method? My gpu powers on with a full speed fan, and I'm looking for a way to simply cut power to it instead of loading the buggy amdgpu driver.

Comment: That is 100% dependent on the motherboard. There is no requirement in the PCIe spec to support anything like that that I am aware of, nor is there a standard API at the OS level. None of the machines I have used appear to have any way to actually cut power to a single PCIe slot.

Comment: @alex.forencich There is flaw in your script. The script removes a device, resets the bridge then rescans the bus. The flaw is that if the bridge is a switch (a bridge with multiple downstream ports) then the reset thereof will propagate to _all_ downstream devices. Also, the reset might affect the bridge itself. The solution is to adjust your script such that it removes all _immediate (nearest child)_ downstream devices instead of only removing `$dev`, then perform the reset, then remove the bridge, then rescan.

Comment: It only resets the port on the bridge, not the whole bridge, so other devices on other ports should not be affected. But yes, you're right, it probably won't work properly with a device with multiple functions.

Comment: Do you have a link to some reference for the magic value used? (Referring to `printf "%04x" $(("0x$bc" | 0x40))`)

Comment: 0x40 is bit 6 in the bridge control register, which is the secondary bus reset bit. It's documented in the PCIe specification. In the gen 3 spec, this is on page 600, in table 7-6 in section 7.5.3.6.

Comment: If you want go back even further, it's defined in the PCI to PCI bridge architecture specification, page 52, table 3-9, section 3.2.5.17.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking in order to exclude the possibility there's something wrong as it does not work for me. But I get a bridge control of 0012 and that converts it to 0052 which is correct. I'm trying to reset a 6700XT that has 2 functions (GPU+Audio). Removed both. Tree is: ```+-03.1-[09-0b]----00.0-[0a-0b]----00.0-[0b]--+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 22
|                                            \-00.1  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device ab28```

Comment: Yeah, the script is a bit limited and only removes one device, that should probably be improved. Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to fully handle all potential cases from userspace, particularly if SRIOV is in use and one or more functions have been handed off to VMs or similar. Anyway, it's possible that the delays need to be tweaked, I have occasionally had issues with devices not appearing after the rescan. But this is required functionality as per the PCIe spec, so it *should* work on all PCIe devices.

Comment: So the script reports bridge 0000:0a:00.0 for both functions (0b:00.0 and 0b:00.1). That bridge is connected to 0000:09:00.0 which in turn is on 0000:00:03.1. Should it be enough to set hte SBR on the immediate port (0a / downstream)? Or should I go further up to the 09/upstream or even 03.1? Everything down this chain is the one GPU on the one PCI slot...

Comment: I think I'll post to reddit, as comments are not suitable for elaborating... Maybe on r/VFIO

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting point, could the GPU have an "internal" PCIe switch? If so, you might have to up a level or two in the hierarchy. You have to reset the port that's upstream of the physical slot. It's possible if there is a faked-out internal switch, the reset bits on that might not be fully implemented.

Answer (score 20):

#### Potential Method #1

I think you can do it with these commands:

**disable**

```
echo 0 > /sys/bus/pci/slots/$NUMBER/power
```

**enable**

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/slots/$NUMBER/power
```

Where `$NUMBER` is the number of the PCI slot.

`lspci -vv` may help to identify the device. This is not very well documented...

#### Potential Method #2

I came across this [thread on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29775/reset-a-pci-device-in-linux), similar issue: there are some answers to that question that say you can reset with this command:

```
echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$NUMBER/reset
```

However, I would read the answers there! There are conditions around doing it this way! Specifically I would [read this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42358/7453)!

#### Potential Method #3

There is a Unix command, `setpci`, that may give you a method for resetting a device in the PCI bus.

I did not see any specific examples with this command so you'll have to google for examples and look through the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setpci). I would tread lightly with this command until you're confident in it's use. From what I've read about it, it's manipulating the hardware directly and so there are always risks in doing it yourself vs. using a tool that is exposing this type of functionality!

Comment: Nothing shows up in slots, even though I have multiple cards plugged in. I do have a power directory in `/sys/bus/pci/devices/$NUMBER/`. But nothing seems to warrant setting 0 or 1

Comment: I came across [this thread on U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29775/reset-a-pci-device-in-linux), similar issue: there are some answers to that Q that say you can reset with this: echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$NUMBER/reset. Read that Q though, there are conditions around doing it that way!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've tried that however and it doesn't seem to do anything. Specifically, the device doesn't power cycle  and the system still knows it is there. (When the card is on and plugged in, there are devices in /dev that I can watch). They don't disappear when I `echo "1" > ...`.

Comment: Are you unloading the kernel modules for that card prior to the power cycling? I think you have to do that as well.

Comment: Good thought, but unfortunately that has no effect. Thanks for all the ideas!

Comment: I think it might not be possible if none of these suggestions worked out? I'll take one more look through google.

Comment: I agree, its mind boggling. I have not figured out how to appropriately use `setpci`, so that could be a solution. As you said, the documentation is poor. I've been searching

Comment: FYI - echo 0 totally seemed to kill the device. I cannot seem to get it back.

Comment: Does this actually cut off the _power_ to the PCIe device?

Comment: @forest - YMMV, some of them did work, but it seemed to depend on H/W to a certain extent.

Comment: For the first or second method? The latter, judging from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci, does not seem like it would be reliable. FWIW, by power off I mean put in the D3 cold state (if I'm understanding the specs correctly).

Comment: I think I'll check the kernel source code to see if toggling `power` actually puts it into D3.

Comment: @slm It looks like `reset` at least will put it into D3 hot, not D3 cold (so power is not actually cut), according to https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/drivers/pci/pci.c#L3590.

Comment: @forest - I'm not following what you're telling/asking me? The link I referenced (#2) states that some H/W supports this, some will not.

Comment: @slm From reading the specs, it seems like all devices should support D3 cold. I'm creating a new question specifically for that, since it won't help me much to try to find an answer in the comments.

Comment: @forest - thank you, that was going to be my next suggestion, raise a new Q and reference this one. I wrote this 5yrs ago and don't remember much beyond what I wrote here. It was basically, YMMV, it was all poorly documented, and was basically inconclusive beyond the leads I presented here.

Comment: 'power' should put the card in D3cold by removing power to the card, but support for this at the motherboard level is uncommon.  'reset' issues an FLR to one function and will not change the card power state.

Comment: No answer to my question so far: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/460928/164143

Comment: @alex.forencich What kind of motherboards support that?

Comment: No idea, I have never personally seen one that can turn off power to the slots.

Comment: @alex.forencich Many PCIe devices might support D3cold, if `d3cold_allowed` in sysfs is set to 1.

Comment: in new kernel, the <id>/power is a dir. So this answer is not useful nowadays

Answer (score 1):

Building off of the answer posted by alex.forencich

I had to make a few changes to get this working on CentOS 7, partly because I am not running as root. This version displays the commands being run.

```
#!/bin/bash

# e.g.  $ ./pcie_hot_reset.sh 04:00.0

DEV=$1

if [ -z "$DEV" ]; then
    echo "Error: no device specified"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -e "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$DEV" ]; then
    DEV="0000:$DEV"
fi

if [ ! -e "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$DEV" ]; then
    echo "Error: device $DEV not found"
    exit 1
fi

PORT=$(basename $(dirname $(readlink "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$DEV")))

if [ ! -e "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$PORT" ]; then
    echo "Error: device $PORT not found"
    exit 1
fi


echo -e "\nRemoving $DEV"

CMD="echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/$DEV/remove"
printf "> $CMD\n"
eval $CMD


echo -e "\nPerforming hot reset of port $PORT"

CMD="setpci -s $PORT BRIDGE_CONTROL"
printf "> $CMD\n"
BR_CTRL=$(eval $CMD)

echo "Bridge control: $BR_CTRL"

CMD="sudo setpci -s $PORT BRIDGE_CONTROL=$(printf "%04x" $((0x${BR_CTRL} | 0x40)))"
printf "> $CMD\n"
eval $CMD
sleep 0.01

CMD="sudo setpci -s $PORT BRIDGE_CONTROL=$BR_CTRL"
printf "> $CMD\n"
eval $CMD
sleep 0.5


echo -e "\nRescanning bus"

CMD="echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/$PORT/rescan"
printf "> $CMD\n"
eval $CMD
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./pcie_hot_reset.sh 04:00.0

Removing 0000:04:00.0
> echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.0/remove
1

Performing hot reset of port 0000:00:03.0
> setpci -s 0000:00:03.0 BRIDGE_CONTROL
Bridge control: 0010
> sudo setpci -s 0000:00:03.0 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0050
> sudo setpci -s 0000:00:03.0 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0010

Rescanning bus
> echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:03.0/rescan
1
```

Comment: What's the advantage of filling the script with a bunch of "sudo" instead of just running the whole script with sudo?

Comment: There is no advantage. It is just a style that often gets used where I work.

Comment: One obvious advantage is that you can run the script as a user.

Comment: there is not rescan file per port, are you sure this is going to work for current kernel?