# How to get power consumption of a PCIe device?

Tags: linux, power-management, pci

I am familiar with `powertop` and `powerstat`, but they appear to measure CPU power consumption. Is there any way to measure the power consumption of a specific PCIe slot?

Comment: any way to get whole power consumption ( CPU + PCI + USB + any other device ) is also good.

Comment: I have the same question. To measure all consumption including PSU I am using simple wattmeter from aliexpress plugged before power cord.

Answer (score 0):

First,

by anyway to get the overall power consumption of the target PC/Server.

Second,

Disable the target PCIe device by:

[How to Reset/Cycle Power to a PCIe Device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73908/how-to-reset-cycle-power-to-a-pcie-device)

Third,

Measure the overall power consumption again.