# Internal PCI-Express WiFi card showing in lspci but not showing in network settings/connections - Linux Mint 21 - 5.15.0-82-generic

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi, intel, iwlwifi

## The issue

In my computer I have this internal WiFi PCIExpress:"Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260"

So, it shows up in `lspci` as:

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
```

And when I do `sudo lshw -c network` I get this

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless-AC 9260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 29
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:38 memory:fc600000-fc603fff
```

But when I run `ip link show` it does not show up:

```
$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
3: wlx7cc2c6146876: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
```

I shortened a little bit the output of `ip link show`
Interface n'3 is the USB wifi dongle that I am using right now as a backup solution in order to have access to the Internet, it is NOT the Intel Wifi Card.

### System log

`dmesg` shows some kind retry init something-something that I don't know the meaning of (good? bad? normal? abnormal?)

```
$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    8.346821] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 0
[    8.346825] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    8.346828] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    8.346829] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    8.346831] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    8.346832] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    8.346833] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    8.346834] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    8.346835] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    8.346837] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    8.346838] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    8.346840] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    8.346841] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    8.346842] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    8.346844] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 20
[    8.346845] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 21
[    8.346846] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 28
[    8.347346] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 46.fae53a8b.0 9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.360070] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz, REV=0x324
[    8.440248] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: retry init count 0
[    8.440283] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz, REV=0x324
[    8.520234] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: retry init count 1
[    8.520262] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz, REV=0x324
[    8.600235] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: retry init count 2
```

### Locating the device in /sys/bus

I think I managed to locate the device's location in /sys/bus at this path

```
# pwd
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/iwlwifi/0000:06:00.0
# pwd -P
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:05.0/0000:06:00.0
```

### Setup

- Distrib: Linux Mint 21
- Kernel: 5.15.0-82-generic #91-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 14 14:14:14 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

### Possible kernel update causing the issue?

This card worked fine so far on this distrib. I guess there was recently a kernel update that probably caused the card to not be working? But this is JUST a guess. By "recently", I mean: the kernel update happened yesterday, then I rebooted to Windows (Dual boot) to end my day with some gaming session. Today morning, I boot my computer up, goes to Linux -> Wifi is not working.

### Resetting the device with a scrip

At this address:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474378/322580

I found that script

```
#!/bin/bash

dev=$1

if [ -z "$dev" ]; then
    echo "Error: no device specified"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -e "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev" ]; then
    dev="0000:$dev"
fi

if [ ! -e "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev" ]; then
    echo "Error: device $dev not found"
    exit 1
fi

port=$(basename $(dirname $(readlink "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev")))

if [ ! -e "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$port" ]; then
    echo "Error: device $port not found"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Removing $dev..."

echo 1 > "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/remove"

echo "Performing hot reset of port $port..."

bc=$(setpci -s $port BRIDGE_CONTROL)

echo "Bridge control:" $bc

setpci -s $port BRIDGE_CONTROL=$(printf "%04x" $(("0x$bc" | 0x40)))
sleep 0.01
setpci -s $port BRIDGE_CONTROL=$bc
sleep 0.5

echo "Rescanning bus..."

echo 1 > "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$port/rescan"
```

That I ran like this on my computer:

```
$ sudo ./pciRescan 06:00.0
```

The ID number `06:00.0` comes from

```
$ lspci | grep Intel
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
```

The execution of the scrip pciRescan did nothing...The Wifi card is still down and invisible for some unidentified reason(s) :')

### Other stuff that I have tried

- Rebooting -> did nothing
- Checking that the Wifi card works on Windows (dual boot on my machine) -> the card works on Windows
- I tried resetting the "reset" bit in /sys/bus/ (see complete path above in this post) -> did nothing, I possibly did this wrong

If I missed anything, if you have suggestions, help, etc. -> don't hesitate.
Thanks in advance for your help <3

EDIT

After reading a lot of stuff online
It sems that the issue is coming from having Windows as a dual boot on the machine
Depending on Windows switches the computer off -> you get this unwanted behavior from the WiFi
So the solution seems to be simply:
Reboot to Windows
Reboot to Linux